# GCC - Using --wrap flag on assert() function

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have a module, lets call it `fut`:

**fut.h**

```
int fut(int n);
```

**fut.c**

```
#include <assert.h>

int fut(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        assert(0);
    }

    return n;
}
```

I want to intercept the call of assert with `--wrap` linker flag, but the linking fails with the message `undefined reference to 'assert'`.
Here is the main function:

```
#include "fut.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static int useRealAssert = 1;
static int assertCalled;

void __real_assert(int expression);

void __wrap_assert(int expression)
{
    if (1 == useRealAssert)
    {
        __real_assert(expression);
    }
    else
    {
        assertCalled = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    useRealAssert = 0;

    printf("Calling fut...\n");
    fut(1);
    printf("assertCalled = %d\n", assertCalled);
}
```

and here is the build command:
`gcc.exe -Wl,--wrap=assert -o my_program main.c fut.c`

Any ideas why this doesn't work for `assert` function? I am doing the same for `malloc` and some other functions, and it works as I expect.

Comment: `assert` is a macro, not a function.

Comment: `if (1 == useRealAssert)` that is kind of odd for an assertion to implement, assertions are for things that can't possibly ever happen. If you are testing assert, I would rather test program termination, as continuing the program after assert fails could cause anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why this doesn't work for assert function?

Because it's a macro, not a function.

**On glibc** https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=assert/assert.h;hb=HEAD `__assert_fail` function is called when assertion fails. On newlib https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/include/assert.h it's `__assert_func`. Depending on the standard C library implementation you are working it can be a different function, but it's easy to check it - just in your IDE jump to definition of assert and inspect the macro definition.